# nhibernate hilo Id generator generates weird Id number

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hilo

I am using nhibernate 3.2 mapping by convention.

here's my code.  in my hilo table, NextHi is 1. I delete all records in User table, then insert a new User there. Instead getting a really small number like 10 or 11, the first user I inserted has Id 32768.  I dont know how i get this number.  please let me know what should I check?

```
            mapper.BeforeMapClass += (modelInspector, type, classCustomizer) =>
                {
                    classCustomizer.Id(c => c.Column("Id"));
                    classCustomizer.Id(c => c.Generator(Generators.HighLow,
                        gmap => gmap.Params(
                            new{
                                max_low = 10, 
                                table = "Hilo", 
                                column = "NextHi", 
                                where = string.Format("TableKey = '{0}'", type.Name.ToLower())
                            })));

                };
```

Comment: If it's an existing database, you don't have IDENTITY enabled for that column do you?!?

Comment: Hmm, strange. Have you tried profiling it with NHProf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter should be named `max_lo`, not `max_low`. It has probably changed between initial (and only by now) description by [Fabio Maulo](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-32-mapping-by-code.html) and the production 3.2 release.

Comment: thank you so much.  it works now. no way I can figure this one out myself.